# xml parsing with expanable details

Tags: android, xml-parsing, expandablelistview

Hi i have one xml parsing example.here i have to add expanadable listview.how is add here.please help me.

this is my code:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "payment_method";
static final String KEY_SUBTOTAL = "subtotal";
static final String KEY_DISCOUNT = "discount";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Intent in = getIntent();
         String subtotal = in.getStringExtra(KEY_SUBTOTAL);
         String discount = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DISCOUNT);
         String payment_method = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);

         TextView lblSub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotal_label);
         TextView lblTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_label);
         TextView lblPayment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.payment_label);

         lblSub.setText(subtotal);
         lbldiscount.setText(discount);
         lblPayment.setText(payment_method);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.
                new String[] { "Order Info" },  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.order},

                // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.single_list_item,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] {"payment_label:"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                new int[] { R.id.payment_label}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Order Info","Order Info " + i ); // the key and it's value.
        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;

}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();
        child.put( "payment_label", "payment_label " + n );

        secList.add( child );
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
    System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
    return true;
}

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}
if i have to click particular product means it is go to next activity.the next activity have detailed description with expandable button.if i have to click the detailed discription means it is expanded and displayed payment_method,subtotal,discount otherwise it is stay in less.please help me.how is to do....How is develop my code with above application.

my main.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/bkg"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:text="No items"/>
```

Here i got the output is zero...what changes is i can to do here.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
check the below code snippet:
ListView lv;
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
gotoActivity();

            }
        });

start your activity in gotoactivity method using startActivityforResult method to take the values
```

Comment: if i have to click the detailed discription means it is expanded and displayed title,artist,duration otherwise it is less.otherwise it is stay in less.please help me.how is to do...i have done expandable listview from this sample example:http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/...but how is to do in my xml parsing code